# Where is the style.qss in the OS? Is it possible to customize the gzclient menus at runtime?

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to customize the gzclient menus.

I see the menus are added on [MainWindow.cc](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/a9352854ba1da2d2ddbad60e43f5bcbc7484e23e/gazebo/gui/MainWindow.cc?at=default#lines-1864)

It seems they are customized at runtime by loading the [:/style.qss](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/a9352854ba1da2d2ddbad60e43f5bcbc7484e23e/gazebo/gui/GuiIface.cc?at=default#lines-237) file at runtime.

I tried to find that file in the `osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-full` docker with `find / -name style.qss` but I couldn't find the file.

Does anybody know where that file is located? I didn't understand the `:` in the filename when loading with [QFile file(":/style.qss");](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/a9352854ba1da2d2ddbad60e43f5bcbc7484e23e/gazebo/gui/GuiIface.cc?at=default#lines-237)

PS: I saw a [similar question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5896/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-gui-with-own-menus-and-buttons/), but there was no answer there, that is why I asked here.

---

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks to @chapulina we have the [custom_gazebo_style](https://github.com/chapulina/custom_gazebo_style) that should do the job.

However, to be able to Compile I had to modify the `CMakeLists.txt` to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5X11Extras REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(gazebo REQUIRED)

QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(resources_RCC resources.qrc)

include_directories(SYSTEM ${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_library(custom_gazebo_style SHARED
  CustomGazeboStyle.cc
  ${resources_RCC}
)
target_link_libraries(custom_gazebo_style ${GAZEBO_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5X11Extras_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5Gui_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES}
    ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES})
```

I modified because of the 5 errors below:

1. /usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
2. /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/gui/qt.h:23:17: fatal error: QtGui: No such file or directory
3. /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/gui/qt.h:24:20: fatal error: QX11Info: No such file or directory
4. /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/gui/qt.h:24:20: fatal error: QX11Info: No such file or directory
5. /usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/gui/qt.h:25:19: fatal error: QWidget: No such file or directory

I'm probably missing something.

After the modifications on `CMakeLists.txt` everything compiled, but I couldn't load the plugin. If I call `gazebo worlds/empty.world --gui-plugin $(pwd)/libcustom_gazebo_style.so --verbose` the program finishes right away with code 255.

If I run `gzserver` instead of `gazebo` (using the same parameters) and then launch `gzclient` (also with the same parameters), gzclient crases with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I checked there was no other gzclient running and `GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345`.

Well, maybe is the version `7.16.0` I'm using with Docker. I may try a different gazebo version to see whether the error goes away.

---

**EDIT 2:**

With `gazebo 9.0.0`, the [custom_gazebo_style](https://github.com/chapulina/custom_gazebo_style) works like a charm.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24101/where-is-the-style.qss-in-the-os?-is-it-possible-to-customize-the-gzclient-menus-at-runtime?/) by [Ruben](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2931/ruben/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hm, the `style.qss` that is found in [resources.qrc](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/1d983d5458989b782977f415d9f01f2b89acbedb/gazebo/gui/resources.qrc#lines-3) is "compiled" inside the binary as explained in [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).

If I understood well, I basically have to recompile the client after modifying the `style.qss`.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2931/ruben/) with karma: 11 on 2019-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Your answer is correct that `style.qss` is compiled within Gazebo and therefore it's not just a matter of finding the file and editing it.

But this doesn't mean you can't change the style some other way. I created an example GUI plugin [here](https://github.com/chapulina/custom_gazebo_style) which loads a custom QSS file at runtime

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruben](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2931/ruben/) on 2019-11-12**:
Hi @chapulina,

Thanks for pointing me to the [custom_gazebo_style](https://github.com/chapulina/custom_gazebo_style)

In Kinetic Docker I'm using `gazebo-7.16.0` and to correctly compile, I had to modify the `CMakeLists.txt`, but I can't add the content here because of the characters limit. I edited the question to add the modified CMakeLists.txt and my results.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2019-11-12**:
Thank you for the changes! I pushed a few of them to the repository and it still works with gazebo9. Maybe the others are not strictly necessary for gazebo7? Feel free to open a pull request with any further changes you may need ;)

**Comment by [Ruben](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2931/ruben/) on 2019-11-12**:
I now tried with `gazebo 9.0.0` and it works like a charm. Ok, I'll add a pull request if I manage to make it work with `gazebo 7`. Thank you very much for having dedicated time to this.